# Cordova CSS scale image on screen

Tags: html, css, cordova

I need a picture of the entire screen, and it works but the image should be the limit that it does not go below the footer and when on portrait the image just "stucks".

[image: image to illustrate the problem]

HTML

```
<!-- Content -->

<div data-role="content">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x288" class="img">
</div>
```

```css
.img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%; /* No effect */
}
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Please provide som HTML as well.

Comment: Well, in landscape, 90% of the height is 90% of the window's height, which may be larger than your content area. The window height includes the header and navigation footer. Have you tried making the height of .img smaller? Say, 50%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was

```
.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 800x;
    border: 1px dotted;
    border-color: red;
}
.img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Thanks Coh3n.